# I have a problem with the following MATLAB code:

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

```
plot(SNR_dB,Rate_op,'--','Linewidth',1.2,'markersize',5,'Color');
hold on;
plot(SNR_dB,Rate_h1,'-o','Linewidth',1.2,'markersize',5,'Color');
hold on;
```

> Error using plot
> Invalid data argument.

how to solve this  problem , i am using 2020 matlab

Comment: You are missing the color specification after `'Color'`. Try something like `plot(SNR_dB,Rate_op,'--','Linewidth',1.2,'markersize',5,'Color','r');`